# How to catch an alertDialogHandler in watin with IE9?

Tags: c#, watin

I am using watin for some web testing and now come up with a strange problem: there is a sign-up page, when clicking the sign-up button, if the security number is not correct, an js pop-up message will show, if the number is correct, the js pop-up won't show. I am testing it with IE9, and the code I am using is like this:

```
var alertDialogHandler = new AlertDialogHandler();
using (new UseDialogOnce(ie.DialogWatcher, alertDialogHandler))
{
  ie.Button(Find.ByName("registe_r")).Click();
  MessageBox.Show(alertDialogHandler.Message);
  if (alertDialogHandler.Exists())
  {
     alertDialogHandler.OKButton.Click();

  }
}
```

Strangely the alertDialogHandler can't be caught, and the code

```
MessageBox.Show(alertDialogHandler.Message);
```

will return an error: "Operation not available. Dialog doesn't exist."

I tried several methods to figure out how to solve this but failed, is there any possibility that it is caused by IE9? I remembered that two years ago when I was using IE7 this worked perfectly fine.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This segment of code works for me on IE9 try it:

```
            AlertDialogHandler alertDialogHandler = new AlertDialogHandler();
            ie.AddDialogHandler(alertDialogHandler );
            ie.Button(Find.ByName("registe_r")).Click();      
            alertDialogHandler.WaitUntilExists();
            alertDialogHandler.OKButton.Click();
            ie.RemoveDialogHandler(alertDialogHandler);
```